# Java Optionals to check input parameters

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I am using to checking input parameters with the java boilerplate like this on the top of the method:

```
public static Boolean filesExist(String file1, String file2, String file3 ... ) {
    if (file1 == null || file2 == null || file3 == null ||...) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (another_param == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
}
```

However, I was reading up on Java 8's optionals and noticed we could do something like this instead:

```
Optional.ofNullable(file1).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
Optional.ofNullable(file2).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
Optional.ofNullable(another_param).orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
...
```

So my question is is there any downside of doing it the second way, I feel that it looks a bit cleaner to me.

Comment: Talking about *cleaner*, how about `if(StringUtils.isAnyBlank(file1, file2, file3)) throw ...`?

Comment: @ernest_k I think its best avoid using third-party API's as answers for pure Java questions.

Comment: One difference is that `Optional` will create an object for each line (which is not really a downside, just something to note) that needs to be garbage collected later. Also, if you plan on adding messages to your exception `Optional` will repeat your message a lot.

Comment: @ernest_k it will throw exception also in case of an empty string

Comment: @user7294900 Correct. I'm aware of that - it's file names, after all...

Comment: @flakes It depends... (and we're in the realm of opinions)

Comment: @ernest_k very fair; I just wouldn't want someone to download a 2MB dependency for a 10 line method ;)

Comment: @ernest_k are you aware that `isAnyBlank` does not the same as the OP’s `null`-checks?

Comment: @cmoetzing even without a message, it’s a lot of code repetition, compared to the original `if` statement.

Comment: @Holger Yes. I suppose a blank string is equally unacceptable as a null, for a file name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For input validation, use [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) instead:

```
public static Boolean filesExist(String file1, String file2, String file3 ... ) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(file1);
    Objects.requireNonNull(file2, "custom message");   
}
```

It is more concise, communicates intention more clearly and does not create an additional `Optional` object. It throws a `NullPointerException`, though.

Comment: Note that `requireNonNull` throws a `NullPointerException`, not an `IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: Would be very easy to implement yourself if you really want it to be `IllegalArgumentException`. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Objects.java#L199)

Comment: I agree with @flakes on this.

Comment: You can also use `Stream.of(file1, file2, file3, …).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull)`. I don’t see the problem with the `NullPointerException`. It tells more about the nature of the problem than an `IllegalArgumentException`. And it’s consistent with the JRE.

Comment: @Holger I'm curious about your opinion... (this has nothing to do with my comment above, which was just about aligning the answer with the behavior in question)... If one validates arguments, then surely an illegalargumentexception makes more sense than a npe... otherwise why not just use parameters and let the jvm raise the npe? (unless of course one is being defensive, which seems obvious in requireNonNull)

Comment: @ernest_k The problem reported via `IllegalArgumentException` could be anything. That’s why we have dedicated exception types, like `NullPointerException`, `NumberFormatException`, `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, allowing us to be more specific. Regarding “why not just use parameters”, i.e. dereference them or delegate to a method known to throw the appropriate exception, that’s precisely what I do when it is obvious that this will happen. When there are multiple parameters and it’s not so obvious or the code could perform irreversible actions before failing, a defensive check is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no downside of doing it this way and the code would work fine,but Optional were introduced to serve a different purpose.For example ,you can use Optional in the method signature in your interface in-order to clearly communicate your clients that the value returned by your method is "Optional".This way your clients don't have to do the guess work.

Comment: The downside is heavy object creation and slower code execution by invoking virtual methods.

Comment: You care about that trade-off only if you are targeting your code to be executed on the resource critical system and if that is the case you will have to avoid using all those "cool" features in Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no downside of doing the second way. Both do the same thing but in a different way. `Optional` is a new feature which was added in Java 8.

Comment: Not quite right. While it is true that both way are operatively the same, they differ in runtime. Lambdas are not just a syntax extension, they have impact on the stack, the memory and execution time.